# images using json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, html, json

I am trying to load an image from the database which is base 64 array into the HTML . it has around 204 characters . I am also trying to load  the name and other details .It returns the following JSON

07-18 18:33:52.732: ERROR/HTMLContacts(1098): Json: google json [{"contactId":"1","contactPhoto":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAIAAABt+uBvAAAAA3NCSVQFBgUzC42AAAAgAElEQVR4\nnK29f4wc93Un+OnvvBq976iarBKnpSnJbbklj3xDL5kldVJAeqVA9Nne0Ih9J0IRvEIiXHf31AQmUelEgUB0V3d2FhfXu450XTBqlf1Cq+J4QqwisQgMaRGYZpTMUCADkZDS6Reik6n\nKApXTsS54kDn7DdXew/2Sre9eFdR3Jer

Good part of it is truncated . I assume that it has crossed JSON limit hence it truncated the other details . Is there any good way to send the array so that i can display image in
HTML ? Thanks in advance .

NOTE : I need to send multiple images maybe 10 at a time .

Comment: How are you generating this JSON? Please show us the code.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn the base-64 string into an image, or why your JSON is being truncated?

Comment: Hmm i already solved it . I compressed if further . I am now wondering how to set the string array ass SRC attribute of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On browser side, you could refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript) for base64 encoding. On server side, the ways variant depending on which language you are using on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

To use the base-64 data in the SRC of an IMG tag, turn it into a data-url, like so (assuming the image is PNG, change the mimetype as appropriate) :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAIAAABt+uBvAAAAA3NCSVQFBgUzC42AAAAgAElEQVR4\nnK29f4wc93Un+OnvvBq976iarBKnpSnJbbklj3xDL5kldVJAeqVA9Nne0Ih9J0IRvEIiXHf31AQmUelEgUB0V3d2FhfXu450XTBqlf1Cq+J4QqwisQgMaRGYZpTMUCADkZDS6Reik6n\nKApXTsS54kDn7DdXew/2Sre9eFdR3Jer">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .It is just a string array "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\...How do i convert to base 64

Comment: I imagine you would convert it to base-64 just like you did originally. The contactPhoto property of your JSON in the original question is already base-64, so use whatever library you used before to convert the string.